# php twitteroauth from Abraham error code 32 at getting aouth url for user authenticating

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

i want to get user authentication access token to access his profile information. when i run the script it thrown the following error

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\promo\app\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php:138

my code is

```
 $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($config['consumer_key'], 
 $config['consumer_secret']); 
 //request token of application
 $request_token = $twitteroauth->oauth(
    'oauth/request_token', [
'oauth_callback' => $config['url_callback']
    ]
 );
 // throw exception if something gone wrong
 if ($twitteroauth->getLastHttpCode() != 200) {
 throw new \Exception('There was a problem performing this request');
 }
 // save token of application to session
 $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
 // generate the URL to make request to authorize our application
 $url = $twitteroauth->url(
    'oauth/authorize', [
'oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']
    ]
 );
 // and redirect
 header('Location: ' . $url);
```

please let me know how to solve that error. according to my finding when the following function call it through the above exception.

```
// request token of application
$request_token = $twitteroauth->oauth(
    'oauth/request_token', [
'oauth_callback' => $config['url_callback']
    ]
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set the redirect url of twitter application and  this resolve my issue of code 32